# Best way to test if an *operator* throws an Exception

Tags: c#, nunit

I have an operator that will throw if the operands aren't appropriate. (Specifically it's doing decimal multiplication on an int-based class - which is permitted if it makes sense (e.g. 2 * 0.5) but throws if the result isn't a round number. (e.g. 2*0.3))

It appears that I can't use nUNit's Assert.Throws<>() to test this, as every way I can think to call it is giving me a compiler error:

```
Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(originalValue * badDecimalMultiplier);
Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(dummy => originalValue * badDecimalMultiplier);
Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(dummy => dummy = originalValue * badDecimalMultiplier);
Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => dummy = originalValue * badDecimalMultiplier);
```

- The first one tries to pass the result of the operation as the parameter to Throws() which fails because Throws only accepts a TestDelegate.
- The second fails with the "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" error.
- The third fails with "Delegate 'NUnit.Framework.TestDelegate' does not take 1 arguments".
- The fourth (and all variations I could find) won't let you assign to an undeclared variable (unsurprising really)

So I think I have to manually catch the Exception and test it?
That or define an actual method to hold the operation, which doesn't seem much better.

Am I missing anything?
If not, could I get confirmation, so that the next person to try to look this up has an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a variable outside the lambda:

```
MyClass dummy;
Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => 
         dummy = originalValue * badDecimalMultiplier);
```

You could also just call a method:

```
Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => 
       (originalValue * badDecimalMultiplier).ToString());
```

Comment: I'm stunned .. I can't believe someone managed to read my question, figure out the answer to it, and type it up, all before I could type up the answer that I'd found before I'd finished posting the question.

I'm in awe of this community

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote the last line, I figure out the solution:

```
  MyIntValuedClass dummy;
  Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => dummy = originalValue * badDecimalMultiplier);
```

Now Throws() is happy as it has a delegate.
The delegate is happy because it has no arguments.
And the operation is happy, because it's assigning to a defined variable.

R# is complaining about dummy never being used, but that's not surprising.

It's not the nicest solution and I'd welcome other ideas, but I wanted to make sure that there was an answer here for the next person to come looking.